# ValidationError: [u"'' value must be a decimal number."] django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model as below

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model)"
    price_one = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    price_two = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

I don't have a ModelForm or just Form for the above model, for some reasons it was displaying as in html terms as below

```
<form class="check_foreign_keys" action="." method="post">
.......
.......
<div class="text-field">
    <label>Price One(US$)</label>
    <div class="input-area">
        <input type="text" name="price_one" id="price_one" value="{{ example_model_obj.price_one }}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-field">
    <label>Price Two(US$)</label>
    <div class="input-area">
        <input type="text" name="price_two" id="price_two" value="{{ example_model_obj.price_two }}" />
    </div>
</div>
 <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="fancy-blue-button" />
</form>
```

**Views.py(Example)**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    obj, created = ExampleModel.objects.get_or_create(price_one=request.POST['price_one'],price_one=request.POST['price_two']......)
    obj.save()
```

**Error:**

```
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 850, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
ValidationError: [u"'' value must be a decimal number."]
```

Here what exactly the problem was, when no value was provided for both `price_one` and `price_two` it was taking the value as '' which was what i want, but as the field DecimalField it was not accepting string/null values even though i have placed `null=True` and `blank=True` for field in the model.

Also i have read on google that the above error can be gone if we use `django.forms.DecimalField`, but i was not using the django form here, just displaying the html elements directly.

So all i want was to take the empty('') values and save to database without the above error `ValidationError: [u"'' value must be a decimal number."]`

Can anyone let me know how to fix the above error ?

Comment: Try changing the input type to number rather than text. Maybe that will send a null rather than an empty string (just a guess at this stage)

Comment: Perhaps do you want to consider using [django-forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django) instead to code by hand.

Comment: sounds like you need to check for `''` and give `None` in its place... also, yeah, just use Django forms, that's what they're for

Comment: Actually i don't only have those two fields , i was displaying the combination of fields from different tables. so displayed them in html terms

Comment: @shivakrishna, mix model properties is not a reason to avoid django-forms. you end up reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Here you are explicitly avoiding all the helpful validation and coercion that  forms will do for you, then being puzzled when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and believe to have found a solution. I noticed that the error report had two parts to it (see below). The line that is significant is line-6:

**Applying store.0005_product_discount_price...Traceback (most recent call last)**

```html
C:\Users\mnede\PycharmProjects\SeshWebsite\SeshStore\static
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, home, sessions, store, taggit, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms,
 wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Applying store.0005_product_discount_price...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1554, in to_python
    return decimal.Decimal(value)
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\schema.py", line 43, in add_field
    super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 395, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 147, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 221, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1583, in get_db_prep_save
    return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(self.to_python(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1559, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value must be a decimal number."]
```

Turns out the error did not occur in my model.py field but actually occurred in my migrations file.

In line with the error report I selected the **0005_product_discount_price.py** in my migrations folder and noticed that the migration django attempted to execute still had the wrong default value included.

```html
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('store', '0004_productpagegalleryimage'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='product',
            name='discount_price',
            field=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default='', max_digits=10),
        ),
    ]
```

The issue was resolved when I imported **from decimal import Decimal**

and changed my code as follows:

```html
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
from decimal import Decimal


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('store', '0004_productpagegalleryimage'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='product',
            name='discount_price',
            field=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0), max_digits=10),
        ),
    ]
```

Django continued to try and execute the false statement, resulting in the two error reports similar the ones you encountered yourself.

Hope this helps.

Z